# How can I print a 4x3 photo on 6x4 photo paper

Tags: windows-7, printing

I want to print a 3"x4" portrait print to fit a photo frame, and have some 6"x4" paper which came with my printer, but I cannot work out how to get Windows to print a portrait 3x4 print - Windows Live Photo Gallery want's to rotate the photo and fit to page.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed word or similar software, just create a document of size 6x4 and paste the image into it, setting its size to 3x4. Watch out when printing to deselect borderless printing, because printers cut of a little bit (and zoom in) when printing borderless.